# Creating a table with percentiles from raw database

Tags: sql-server

I have a database with 160 million something records in it, that is segmented by an code called TMC. The TMC represents a section of highway that is then measured every five minutes for speed and travel time. So the TMC isn't a unique identifier as it the same for every five minutes for all days of the year for that one section of highway. There are 3,440 unique TMCs, as for each TMC, I am trying to calculate a percentile of travel times for an entire year for a specific time of day.

I can get the code for the percentiles to work, but I do not understand how to create and update a table in SQL so the percentiles can be dumped and stored within it. Something to do with the with statement being used to get the percentile does not mesh well with update functions. I normally just use select and copy the data into excel, and then reimport the data into my SQL database, but I am trying to see if I can automate this process as much as possible.

Here is the code that I got so far.

```
create table TMCF5 (
TMC_code varchar(50),
P95M varchar(50),
P50M varchar(50),
P95A varchar(50),
P50A varchar(50))

go

WITH PERCENTILES_Afternoon AS (SELECT TMC_code, EPOCH, percentile_CONT(.95)  
WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY cast(travel_time_minutes as float)) OVER (PARTITION BY TMC_code) AS P95afternoon, percentile_CONT(.50)  
WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY cast(travel_time_minutes as float)) OVER (PARTITION BY TMC_code) AS P50afternoon  FROM [dbo].[AR_2018_TRUCKS_1_3]
WHERE DATEPART(HOUR, EPOCH) between 16 and 17  AND (WKDAY != 'SAT' and WKDAY != 'SUN'))

insert tmcf5 (tmc_code) select tmc_code from percentiles_afternoon group by tmc_code

go

WITH PERCENTILES_Afternoon2 AS (SELECT TMC_code, EPOCH, percentile_CONT(.95)  
WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY cast(travel_time_minutes as float)) OVER (PARTITION BY TMC_code) AS P95afternoon, percentile_CONT(.50)  
WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY cast(travel_time_minutes as float)) OVER (PARTITION BY TMC_code) AS P50afternoon  FROM [dbo].[AR_2018_TRUCKS_1_3]
WHERE DATEPART(HOUR, EPOCH) between 16 and 17  AND (WKDAY != 'SAT' and WKDAY != 'SUN'))

update TMCF5 set tmcF5.p95A = percentiles_Afternoon2.P95Afternoon from percentiles_afternoon2
join percentiles_afternoon2 on tmcf5.tmc_code = percentiles_afternoon2.tmc_code
```

Comment: `insert tmcf5` should be `insert into tmcf5`

Comment: Please stop posting the same question over and over and continuing to not include details so people understand your problem. I truly hope you find a solution.

Comment: I thought I did include details per your suggestion.

Comment: Where is the sample data? What about the desired output? All things for a [mcve] so we can actually write a query.

Comment: @benfardot.  "Something to do with..." is not helpful.  What is the wording of the error message you're encountering?  Also, is there a simplified version of your problem that you can make up, preferably one with sample data and immediately reproducible by the user with simply copy/paste.  You'll attract a lot more helpers if your details make it easier for them to help you.

Comment: Here is a chunk of the data:

Comment: Here is a chunk of the data:
TMC                Travel_time
113P07005 0.79
113P07005 0.61
113P07005 1.31
113P07005 1.25
113P07005 1.87
113P07005 1.31
113P07005 1.25

I want the output to be a single TMC with the numbers condensed into a 95th percentile. Then done an additional 3,440 times with other TMCs and stored in a table on my database. So the end result is a table with 3,440 rows and two columns.

Comment: The error I am getting is: The correlation name 'percentiles_afternoon2' is specified multiple times in a FROM clause.

Answer (score 0):

The text in your error message that you provided in the comments leads me to identify the problem as being present in this statement:

```
update TMCF5 set tmcF5.p95A = percentiles_Afternoon2.P95Afternoon from percentiles_afternoon2
join percentiles_afternoon2 on tmcf5.tmc_code = percentiles_afternoon2.tmc_code
```

It has 'percentiles_afternoon2' listed as both tables.  It seems you wanted to reference 'tmcf5' as one of your objects.

Also, if your first insert statement purely serves the purpose of bringing in your tmc_codes, then just simplify the query to:

```
-- no cte's

insert     tmcf5 (tmc_code)
select 
distinct   tmc_code 
from       AR_2018_TRUCKS_1_3;
```

Comment: Ah ok, I was referencing the wrong table after the join statement. Everything works as intended.

Comment: @benfardot, that's good to hear.  Please upvote/accept the answer if it worked out for you.